# Estou tentando mover um arquivo que esta dentro de um Array usando renameTo

Tags: java, array

Olá, sou novo com java e estou com dificuldades para utilizar o "renameTo".
e nessa atividade eu tenho que mover arquivos não atendam as seguintes exigências

1. Não esteja vazio;
2. Cada linha do arquivo tenha a quantidade exata de colunas esperadas a serem importadas

Até ai tudo bem!
Minha dificuldade está em mover para as pastas!
Segue o código

Estou pegando arquivos .csv aqui!

```
try {
         File arquivos[];
            File diretorio = new File("C:\\Users\\akyri\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\LeitoDeCsv\\PENDENTES");
            arquivos = diretorio.listFiles();
         
            for(int i = 0; i < arquivos.length; i++){
                   //leia arquivos[i];
                
                //Pega o arquivo e manda ler
              ConteudoCSV = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(arquivos[i]));
```

E aqui estou verificando e exibindo o código

```
 while((linha = ConteudoCSV.readLine()) != null){
                  //Trata a linha vazia que está no CSV!
                  if( linha.trim().isEmpty() ) {
                      continue;
                  }
                    
                  
                  //Vai "contar" a linha a cada ";"
              String[] venda = linha.split(csvSeparadorCompo);
              
              var quant = venda.length;
              if(quant != 4) {
                  
                
                  
                   boolean ok = arquivos[i].renameTo(new File(DiretorioInvalidos,arquivos[i].getName()));
                   if(ok){
                        System.out.println("Arquivo foi movido com sucesso");
                    }
                   else{
                        System.out.println("Nao foi possivel mover o arquivo");
                    }
              
              }
            
              System.out.println("[venda = " + venda[0]
                                + ", Nome = " + venda[1]
                                + ", Data = " + venda[2]
                                + ", Preço = " + venda[3]);
              
              
                  
          
            }    
            }
```

O problemas é que boolean está sempre retornando false!
alguém me diz oque eu estou fazendo de errado.
Grato!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há uma boa chance de estar havendo um conflito de arquivos com mesmo nome na pasta de destino, por isso o método retorna false.